# Highlight reactive elements when they are inserted into the DOM - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor

I want to know how I can highlight new elements with `$('.game-panel').effect('highlight');` (jQuery UI) immediately after they are inserted into the DOM.

```
    {{#each games}}
       {{> game}}
    {{/each}}

<template name="game">
    <div class="game-panel">
       Test
    </div>
</template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the rendered callback.

```
Template.game.rendered=function(){
  this.$('.game-panel').effect('highlight');
};
```

There is also a yet undocumented API called "UI hooks" which theorically could allow finer grained control over when elements get inserted in the DOM.

Announcement on meteor-core :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw/j4bNvXu36IoJ

Example of use :

https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper/blob/master/transition-helper.js

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this does not work for me. It highlights all games on page rendering that currently exists in the db, not those new elements which, are inserted after page rendering.